# Create empty table from type in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I have type

```
        CREATE TYPE p_store.MY_TYPE AS
        (
            session_id               BIGINT,
            column2                  INTEGER
        );
```

And function that return

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_empty_type_creation_function() RETURNS MY_TYPE AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN NULL;
    END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
    PARALLEL SAFE;
```

But i cant use where clause with table that created by my_empty_type_creation_function

when i call

```
    SELECT * FROM (select my_empty_type_creation_function() alias_1) WHERE alias_1.session_id is null;
```

i get an exception, that column `session_id` does not exist

How to create function that will return empty table, or how to make correct `WHERE` clause in such a situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the function definition given, you need to expand the columns from the function result:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT (my_empty_type_creation_function()).*
) t
where session_id is null;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/4BCybEbx)

---

However it looks like you actually want a function that returns a result set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_empty_type_creation_function() 
  RETURNS setof MY_TYPE 
AS
$$
begin
  return next null::my_type;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select *
from my_empty_type_creation_function()
where session_id is null
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/DOZekNt_)

---

But I would recommend to get rid of the custom type and define your function as `returns table (session_id bigint, column2 int)` instead.

Comment: I belive, that your example work, but i try all what you say. In first example i get the same exception, that column does not exist. In second variant (i modify function), the same exception, column does not exist...

Comment: @BestowsInConstructing: the first query works without an error https://dbfiddle.uk/Vj0x7Whv